# Signing a message with HDWalletProvider?

Tags: web3js, hd-wallets

This works fine:

```
const provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:8545');
const web3 = new Web3(provider);

await web3.eth.sign(message, address);
```

But when I switch to this provider:

```
const provider = new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, "https://rinkeby.infura.io/<key>", 0 )
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: self.signMessage is not a function
```

Anyone know what might be the issue?

Thanks!

*edit* I guess it's not implemented. Anyone know an alternative way to sign something using Infura?

Comment: Assuming this is the `HDWalletProvider` you're using, it looks like they simply don't implement it: https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle-hdwallet-provider/blob/master/index.js#L28.

Comment: Do you have fixed this bug? I'm facing the same problem.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/30000)